# segmentation fault 11 при компиляции в командой строке

Tags: c, указатели, структуры, segmentation-fault

У меня возникла проблема, может быть кто то сможет помочь, это программа дека, с возможность добавления и изъятия числа как с конца так и с начала списка. Когда работаю и компилирую её в xcode - всё отлично работает без нареканий. Когда запускаю компилятор через командую строку, то возникает segmentation fault 11. В чём может быть причина и как искать эти ошибки сегментации?
Заранее спасибо за помощь ( p.s. .h файл не добавил в листинг но он существует :)) )

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dequeue.h"
dequeue* dequeue_create() {
dequeue *new_dequeue = (dequeue*) malloc(sizeof(dequeue));
//new_dequeue->next = new_dequeue->prev = new_dequeue->last = new_dequeue->first = NULL;
return new_dequeue;
}
void dequeue_push_front(dequeue** dq, int data)
{
// TODO: add a new element at the beginning of the queue
 dequeue *new_dequeue = (dequeue*) malloc(sizeof(dequeue));
 if (new_dequeue == NULL) {
     exit(1);
 }
 if ((*dq)->prev == NULL )
 {
     (*dq)->prev = new_dequeue;
     (*dq)->next = new_dequeue;
 }
 else {
     (*dq)->prev->prev = new_dequeue ;
     new_dequeue->next = (*dq)->prev;
     (*dq)->prev = new_dequeue;
 }
 new_dequeue->data = data;
 new_dequeue->prev = NULL;
}

void dequeue_push_back(dequeue** dq, int data)
{
// TODO: add a new element at the end of the queue
 dequeue *new_dequeue = (dequeue*) malloc(sizeof(dequeue));
if (new_dequeue == NULL) {
exit(1);
}
if ((*dq)->next == NULL )
{
    (*dq)->prev = new_dequeue;
    (*dq)->next = new_dequeue;
}
else{
    (*dq)->next->next = new_dequeue;
    new_dequeue->prev = (*dq)->next;
    (*dq)->next = new_dequeue;
}
 new_dequeue->data = data;
 new_dequeue->next = NULL;

}

int dequeue_pop_front(dequeue** dq)
{
// TODO: retrieve the data of the first element and remove it from      the queue
//       return zero if queue is empty
int ret_numb;
dequeue *p_dequeue;

if( (*dq)->prev == NULL && (*dq)->next == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

if( (*dq)->prev == (*dq)->next){
    ret_numb = (*dq)->prev->data;
    free((*dq)->prev);
    (*dq)->prev = (*dq)->next = NULL;
    return ret_numb;
}

ret_numb = (*dq)->prev->data;
p_dequeue = (*dq)->prev->next;
p_dequeue->prev = NULL;
free((*dq)->prev);
(*dq)->prev = p_dequeue;
return ret_numb;
}

int dequeue_pop_back(dequeue** dq)
{
// TODO: retrieve the data of the last element and remove it from the queue
//       return zero if queue is empty
int ret_numb;
dequeue *p_dequeue;

if( (*dq)->prev == NULL && (*dq)->next == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

if( (*dq)->prev == (*dq)->next){
    ret_numb = (*dq)->prev->data;
    free((*dq)->next);
    (*dq)->prev = (*dq)->next = NULL;
    return ret_numb;
}

ret_numb = (*dq)->next->data;
p_dequeue = (*dq)->next->prev;
p_dequeue->next = NULL;
free((*dq)->next);
(*dq)->next = p_dequeue;
return ret_numb;


return 0;
}

void dequeue_destroy(dequeue** dq) {
// TODO: destroy the queue,
// free everything so that no memory leak occurs
if((*dq)->next == NULL && (*dq)->prev == NULL ) {
    free(*dq);
}
else{
    dequeue *p_dequeue;
    do{
        p_dequeue = (*dq)->prev->next;
        free((*dq)->prev);
        (*dq)->prev = p_dequeue;
    } while ((*dq)->prev != (*dq)->next);
    free((*dq)->prev);
    free(*dq);
    }
}
```

Функция main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dequeue.h"

int main() {
dequeue* dq = dequeue_create();

dequeue_push_front(&dq, 1);
dequeue_push_back(&dq, 2);
dequeue_push_front(&dq, 3);
dequeue_push_back(&dq, 4);
dequeue_push_back(&dq, 15);
dequeue_push_back(&dq, 32);
dequeue_push_front(&dq, 98);

for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= 7; cnt++) {
    printf("%d ", dequeue_pop_front(&dq));
}
printf("\n");
dequeue_destroy(&dq);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что видно под отладчиком (на какой строке падает, из-за какого действия), что говорит valgrind?

Comment: Может у меня дурацкий компилятор в командой строке ( я им особо пользоваться не умею, всегда работаю в xcode ), но он особо не блещет информативностью
"wl-c-21:leak-check a1$ ./double_ended_queue.out
Segmentation fault: 11"
это всё что он сообщает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная функция

```
dequeue* dequeue_create() {
dequeue *new_dequeue = (dequeue*) malloc(sizeof(dequeue));
//new_dequeue->next = new_dequeue->prev = new_dequeue->last = new_dequeue->first = NULL;
return new_dequeue;
}
```

не инициализирует поля созданного элемента типа `dequeue`, такие как, например, `prev` или `next`.. Поэтому вызов функции `dequeue_push_front` имеет неопределенное поведение.

```
void dequeue_push_front(dequeue** dq, int data)
{
// TODO: add a new element at the beginning of the queue
 dequeue *new_dequeue = (dequeue*) malloc(sizeof(dequeue));
 if (new_dequeue == NULL) {
     exit(1);
 }
 if ((*dq)->prev == NULL )
      ^^^^^^^^^^
 {
     (*dq)->prev = new_dequeue;
     (*dq)->next = new_dequeue;
 }

//...
```

Лучше было бы, если функция `dequeue_create`  просто возвращала `NULL`, а все остальные функции, как, например, `dequeue_push_front` проверяли бы, равно ли значение  `*dq` `NULL`, и действовали в соответствии с этой проверкой.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ, а можно поподробнее что значит не "инициализирует поле"? и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Просто дописать что то из разряда  
new_dequeue->next = new_dequeue->prev = NULL; ?

Comment: @AntonBarinov Например, поле prev у созданного элемента функцией dequeue_create имеет неопределенное значение.

Comment: Просто дописать что то из разряда new_dequeue->next = new_dequeue->prev = NULL; и  new_dequeue->data = 0; ?

Comment: спасибо, разобрался, теперь работает